# Fail to execute code with nested layouts in android

Tags: android, layout, view

Hi here is the code in question (I've verified that everything that is not here is working, as far as I can see):

Now SchemeLayout, CityLayout, MastermidLayout, HQLayout and HandLayout are all Linear Layouts with specific dimensions for my screen. Each of them have a different color and hence I know exactly their size and where they are placed. Then I create a handfull of secondary layouts just so that the screen will be split as I want:

```
    LinearLayout schemeandcity = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout masterandhq = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout cards = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout cardsandecks = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout Complete = new LinearLayout(this);

    schemeandcity.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    masterandhq.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    cards.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    cardsandecks.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    Complete.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    schemeandcity.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    masterandhq.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    cards.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    cardsandecks.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    Complete.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    schemeandcity.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    masterandhq.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    cards.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    cardsandecks.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    Complete.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    schemeandcity.addView(SchemeLayout);
    schemeandcity.addView(CityLayout);
    masterandhq.addView(MastermindLayout);
    masterandhq.addView(HQLayout);
    cards.addView(HandLayout);
    cards.addView(masterandhq);
    cards.addView(schemeandcity);
    //cardsandecks.addView(cards);
    //cardsandecks.addView(DecksLayout);
    //Complete.addView(cardsandecks);
    Complete.addView(cards);
    //Complete.addView(CBarLayout);


    setContentView(Complete);
```

Each Now for the code that fails. In the code above I only show the cards sublayout. The code:

```
    cards.addView(HandLayout);
    cards.addView(masterandhq);
```

Shows me both layouts but

```
    cards.addView(masterandhq);
    cards.addView(HandLayout);
```

Only shows me the first (masterandhq). Its as if after I add a compound layout then I cannot add anything else. Oh.. and of course none of the versions show me schemeandcity.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`masterandhq` has layout_height and width set to `match_parent` so when you add it to your linear layout it take the whole space anything you add after that will be out of screen.

Comment: Yes!! I've fixed it by calculating resulting widths and heights. Thank you very much!